# Javascript confirm in if condition statement in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, confirm

I've javascript confirmation function like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function Confirm() {
        var confirm_value = document.createElement("INPUT");
        confirm_value.type = "hidden";
        confirm_value.name = "confirm_value";
        if (confirm("Your team is incomplete. Do you want to save data?")) {
            confirm_value.value = "Yes";
        } else {
            confirm_value.value = "No";
        }
        document.forms[0].appendChild(confirm_value);
    }
</script>
```

I want to show this when the team really incomplete. I check it in save button click. If false; I want to call JS confirm function:

```
if ((teamList.Contains("Purchasing") && teamList.Contains("Quality") && teamList.Contains("Process") && teamList.Contains("R&D")))
    { }
else
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "Confirm()", true);
    }
```

If confirm returns yes, I want to save them. If no, I don't want to save them.

```
string confirmValue = Request.Form["confirm_value"];
if (confirmValue == "Yes")
{
    // Do save operations
}
```

These code snippets returns null first time, and it returns my confirm answer (yes or no) when the other button clicks.

How can I do?